# Can react-query make sequential network calls and wait for previous one to finish?

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, react-query, tanstackreact-query

In the following code for example, how can I update react-query to wait for the previous call to be complete before starting the next one?

I'm trying to hit an API that has rate limiting to one call at a time but I have a list of calls I need to make, I get a 429 if more than one are done at the same time.

```
const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState([])

const results = useQueries(
  selection.map(item => ({
    queryKey: ['something', item]
    queryFn: () => fetchItem(item)
   })
)

const data = results.map(result => result.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a built-in solution.

But how about this. A state that counts queries that have been run, and enables the next query.

You might need `staleTime: Infinity` to make sure the library doesn't refetch all queries at the same time.

```js
const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState([])
const [noCompleted, setNoCompleted] = React.useState(0)

const results = useQueries(
  selection.map((item, i) => ({
    queryKey: ['something', item]
    queryFn: () => fetchItem(item)
    enabled: i <= noCompleted
    staleTime: Infinity
    cacheTime: Infinity
   })
)

const firstLoading = results.findIndex((r) => r.isLoading)

React.useEffect(() => {
  setNoCompleted(firstLoading)
}, [firstLoading])
```

Comment: hmm, the reason I need it consequentially is because the API I'm hitting has a rate limit of 1 call at a time. I worry this route we could be stuck here for a while getting 429 errors over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8571434/anton) suggested, React Query [exposes a method](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/disabling-queries) called `enabled`. to illustrate it for you, use normal methods to loop through your items, and then only call RQ when the previous query finished, and then toggling the `enabled` state. This is a very rough, more verbose example, and running [replit here](https://replit.com/@potgied/EnlightenedDamagedTree#src/App.tsx).

I also included how to reuse the cache in the replit, so let me know if it makes sense. It can most definitely be optimised better, and the `setTimeout` is only to show you visually the progress.

```js
async function getCoins(coin: string): Promise<APIResponse> {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.gemini.com/v2/ticker/${coin}usd`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

export function useCoin(coins: string[]) {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState<APIResponse[]>([]);

  const query = useQuery(['coinData', coins[currentIndex]], () => getCoins(coins[currentIndex]), {
    enabled: currentIndex < coins.length,
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setAllData(prev => [...prev, data]);
        setCurrentIndex(prev => prev + 1);
      }, 1500)
    }
  });
  return { ...query, data: allData };
}

export function CachedEntries() {
  const [eth, setEth] = useState<APIResponse | null>(null)
  const cached = queryClient.getQueryData<APIResponse>(['coinData', 'eth'])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cached) {
      setEth(cached);
    }
  }, [cached]);

  return eth !== null ? (
     <div>Entries from cache:
        <div key={eth?.symbol}>{eth?.symbol}: {eth?.close}</div>
      </div>
  ) : null
}

export function Entries() {
  const { data, error, isError } = useCoin(['btc', 'eth']);

  if (isError) console.log(error)

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Entries from query:
        <div>{data?.map(coin => (
          <div key={coin.symbol}>{coin.symbol}: {coin.close}</div>
        ))}</div>
      </div>
      <CachedEntries />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the example from [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8571434/anton), he uses the built in `useQueries` which would be a better approach. Hopefully between the two answers you can understand how to use RQ, how it works, and cool things you can do with it.